# Workflow with Modman and Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, modman, workflow

**UPDATE**

When I was reposting this edit I'd come to realize that you can only develop directly in the modules, since it would be idiotic to develop in the Magento source, move the code to the module and then create the symlinks. Sorry for wasting your time.

**Original Post**

I have just taking over a project that uses Modman with a Magento installation. I understand, that it uses Modman to create symlinks between the Magento installation and the modules you're building. So far so good.

The thing that bothers me is, I can not see how you would develop something without testing all the time and if you build it in a folder beside the Magento installation, should I "compile" it (create the symlinks), every time I make a change?

**How do you guys keep a good workflow when developing with Modman?**

If you haven't guessed, I'm pretty new to developing in Magento and with Modman, so bare with me.

// Ulrik McArdle

Comment: No there is no need to redeploy on _every_ change. Check the [wiki](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/wiki) for more information. I believe requests for workflow descriptions are too broad for a Q&A format. I voted to close this in favour of more specific questions – if they arise after consulting the wiki.

Comment: @mam08ixo i would like to know how it will work with Window OS ... I will one brief answer required on Modman

Comment: don't be that lazy, rtfm! it's all [there](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/blob/1.12/README.md#windows-users)!